# MsiSetTargetPathA to an old folder fails with 1315 on Upgrade (Unable to write to the specified folder)

Tags: c++, permissions, wix, windows-installer, installshield

#### Preface

We have changed the default installation folder for a product, but there is a requirement from our existing clients to preserve the old installation path on an upgrade. *Update:* standalone `msi` and `msm` modules are built with Wix. However, the whole project is built with InstallShield using Wix `msm`s modules. So the CustomAction should be reusable in both project types (Wix and InstallShield).

#### Chosen solution

Since the `INSTALLDIR` entry in a `Directory` table has changed, I need to find the path of the installed product and modify `INSTALLDIR` during a custom action.

This is a part of `AssignOldPathOnUpgrade` CustomAction's code, which is executed right after `CostFinalize`:

```
        guid_str_t guidBuffer{};
        auto bufferLenght = DWORD(guidBuffer.size());

        constexpr const auto propUpgradingProduct = "UPGRADING_PRODUCT";

        UINT res = MsiGetPropertyA(hInstall,
            propUpgradingProduct,
            guidBuffer.data(),
            &bufferLenght);

        if (ERROR_SUCCESS != res)
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed to get property \"") +
                propUpgradingProduct + 
                "\", Error: " +
                getLastError());

        logMessage(std::string() + __func__ + ": current INSTALLDIR = \"" + getCurrentInstallDir() + "\"");

        const auto& oldPath = getPathByGUID(guidBuffer);
        logMessage(std::string() + __func__ + ": setting INSTALLDIR to old path: \"" + oldPath + "\"");

        constexpr const auto installFolderIdentifier = "INSTALLDIR";
        res = MsiSetTargetPathA(hInstall, installFolderIdentifier, oldPath.c_str());

        if (ERROR_SUCCESS != res)
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed to set INSTALLDIR on an product update. Error: ") +
                getLastError());
```

Here is the Wix definition:

```
<Fragment>
  <CustomAction Id="AssignOldPathOnUpgrade"
                BinaryKey="DLServiceCA"
                DllEntry="AssignOldPathOnUpgrade"
                Execute="immediate"
                Impersonate="no"
                Return="check" />
  <Binary Id="DLServiceCA" SourceFile="$(var.DLServiceCA.TargetPath)" />
</Fragment>
```

And Wix `InstallExecuteSequence`:

```
      <Custom Action="AssignOldPathOnUpgrade" After="CostFinalize">
          UPGRADING_PRODUCT
      </Custom>
```

#### The Problem

The CustiomAction fails due to `MsiSetTargetPathA` returning `ERROR_DIRECTORY` with Installer's internal error `1315` which stands for *Unable to write to the specified folder*.

1. If the upgrade installation is run by a user who is a member of `Administrators` group: shortly after launch UAC asks for elevation. And `1315` error occurres when `AssignOldPathOnUpgrade` is invoked.
2. If the upgrade installation is run with the administrative priviliges (*Run as Administrator*), the upgrade is successfull and the new version is copied to the old path.
3. **Previous upgrades that had the same (hardcoded) default directory for installation as the old one are successful when launched by a user with UAC elevation (the 1st scenario)**.

#### Dirctory component

The Wix project for all the previous versions creates the `INSTALLDIR` via a `Component` and assigns priviliges:

```
<Fragment>
    <?if $(sys.BUILDARCH) = x86?>
      <?define INSTALLDIRComponent.Id = "{155AB3A7-0160-419D-AC7D-7BA88AF6E938}" ?>
    <?elseif $(sys.BUILDARCH) = x64?>
      <?define INSTALLDIRComponent.Id = "{E2186CCC-A834-4F37-B58C-F55A11E9E5DD}" ?>
    <?endif?>

    <Component Directory="INSTALLDIR"
               Id="INSTALLDIRComponent"
               Guid="$(var.INSTALLDIRComponent.Id)"
               Location="local"
               Win64="$(var.Win64)" >

      <CreateFolder>
        <Permission User="Administrators" GenericAll="yes"/>
        <Permission User="Everyone" Read="yes" GenericRead="yes"/>
      </CreateFolder>
    </Component>
</Fragment>
```

#### Conclusion

1. How can I solve the problem with this error (without some insanelly convoluted workarounds)? User must be able to do an upgrade with UAC elevation just like with previos versions.
2. Why is it possible to upgrade (with UAC elevation) to an old path when `INSTALLDIR` is hardcoded, but `1315` error occurres when `MsiSetTargetPathA` is called?

---

#### Update

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msiquery/nf-msiquery-msisettargetpatha) says:

> MsiSetTargetPath fails if the selected directory is read only.

When I enable `Read` permission for `Users` group, `MsiSetTargetPathA` succeeds. But it is not ever enabled for `Users`, so toggling this prmission between calls to `MsiSetTargetPathA` is **not an option**.

---

#### UPDATE 2

After allowing UAC to proceed with installation I found out, that the msi process from the current user is **not** elevated:
[image]

Hence, I think it does not act on behalf of an Administrator (however, *dummy* is a member of *Administrators* group), so the Permission to *Write* does not apply to *dummy* in an unelevated context.
*Why does it successfully copy files to the directory when the path is hardcoded?* - I guess it is because the copying is performed by the SYSTEM. This is a guess though.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`SetDirectory`](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/setdirectory.html) to change the directory path. If you really need to run custom code to get the previous path, then it should set a new property and then a `SetDirectory` should set the directory to the value using that new property.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to somehow acquire the previous path without using a CustomAction? As you see, now I get GUID from `UPDATING_PRODUCT` entry which is set in `Upgrade` Table and then get the path from within a CustomAction. It would be great to avoid using CustomAction at all...

Comment: Also, according to documentation, successfull `MsiSetTargetPath` invocation will also update all the `Directory` table records that depend on the current entry. That is, all the relative path will be changed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/custom-action-type-51 (which is generated by `SetDirectory`) does not mention anything about updating `Directory` table. Maybe Wix's `SetDirectory` implements this, but I also need my CustomAction in InstallShield project.

Comment: I think the documentation you're looking for is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/changing-the-target-location-for-a-directory.

Comment: For getting the previous path without a CustomAction, use the Remember Property pattern - https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/